# Timing marks way off

Tags: timing

1995 Nissan 6cyl. 3.0

Tried to get truck smogged.  Did not pass timing test as the marks on the flywheel were not even in site.  The truck runs great, you can hardly feel the idle. nice and smooth, lots of pep.   Why are these marks so far off.

Comment: Perhaps the flywheel was fitted incorrectly during a clutch change? Some engine control systems are independent of the flywheel, others have sensors using the flywheel...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This truck has not been worked on in the last few years. It passed smog test two years ago.  6000 miles on it since. No work has been done. The marks on the flywheel seem to be half way around the pully,  They are very clear white marks,no dirt or grease. How can this truck run, if the timing is so far off.

Comment: The fact that the truck runs well is conclusive that the timing isn't off, but is exactly on or pretty close to it. Something else, as @Solar Mike observes in his comment above, is going on.

Comment: could the timing light itself be defective or the number one plug, or the plug wires?  I am not a mechanic so, Around a year ago, the rotor in the distrib. broke.  the truck stalled out.  I replace the rotor and I was back in business.  Could the distributor be the problem?   I bought this truck new and it is still in mint condition, not worth much, but I cannot bear to let it go. Other than this problem, everything in or on it is perfect. Has been garaged kept for 25 years.

Comment: Flywheel?, You mean harmonic balancer? If so most HB's are manufactured with an outer ring that can move after the rubber that is in between the inner and outer rings deteriorates, this would make the mark off. Replace the balancer.

Comment: You are timing off #1 cylinder, yes?

Comment: George:  Yes, I am hooking up timing light to plug wire #1

Comment: Moab:  I did not really mean flywheel.

Comment: Thanks for all the help and input from you guys.  I really appreciated the advice.  PROBLEM SOLVED;  The pulley with the timing marks has six bolts holding it on, the mechanic that changed my timing belt about 8 years ago put it on, off by 3 holes.(there are 6 ways it will fit)   Requirement for timing for smog(california) started this year as I am told.  So the truck has not had a timing light test for about 8 years and it was never noticed.(as the engine purrs all the time)   Hope this will help others with a 180 degree off timing problem.